# I can't compile a Qt project I downloaded from the internet

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt

I'm trying to compile this application from GitHub:

https://github.com/fffaraz/Lan-Messenger

With both Qt4 and Qt5, I get these errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQtGui
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQtNetwork
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQtCore
```

I tried changing links in /usr/lib.

It compiles on Windows but won't run because of errors with the DLLs.

Comment: You must probably just download Qt Creator without Qt libs.

Comment: The question was long and this hostile fork removed most of what I wrote but I did install libqt4-dev libraries and others too. I think it solved the problem the first time. After I made an update from Qt4 to Qt5 both of them broke

Answer (score 0):

Your Compiler can not find required library.

Before start up

on the project right click and clean your project, after again right click and run qmake and then build again

Add this if does not exist in your *.pro file;

```
QT    += gui core network
```

be sure your Qt installed correctly.

on www.qt.io online installer is installing all required libraries and files for you and you start up your project any configuration.

thats project worked for me Qt 5.5.1 in Windows 7

Comment: Could you tell me how I could diagnose why the linker can't find these libraries on linux? I'm using ubuntu. Like I said, it worked before but it broke at some point. I'm using this project file https://github.com/fffaraz/Lan-Messenger/blob/master/Lan-Messenger/LanMessenger.pro The problem I'm having on windows is some dll related problem(I think). I will post a screen grab when I get back to that windows machine.

Comment: Open up a Terminal, go to the directory of your **.pro** file and execute `qmake` in the command line.